# Gridview: Loses OnItemClickHandler

Tags: android, gridview, event-handling

I'm currently stuck with a very strange error. I have a gridview which is filled with some custom views. The click handler works as aspected as long as I don't scroll.

But when I scroll down the event handler got lost and don't react anymore. I already tried to add a onScrollEventHandler but that seems to get lost too.

The code is pretty standard:

```
    grdVwUser = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grdVwUser);
    grdVwUser.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GOT CLICKED");

            final Intent intent = getMyIntent(); // intent for another activity
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Any idea what that could be?

Additionally: I also got this error message in logcat

```
02-02 14:02:23.636: W/KeyCharacterMap(13871): Bad keycharmap - filesize=32
02-02 14:02:23.636: W/KeyCharacterMap(13871): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/bravo-keypad.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.0.devname='bravo-keypad'
02-02 14:02:23.636: W/KeyCharacterMap(13871): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

But further more, the GC seems to be doing a lot of work:

```
   02-02 15:51:11.956: D/dalvikvm(16606): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11572 objects / 678832 bytes in 62ms
   02-02 15:51:12.096: D/dalvikvm(16606): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1581 objects / 65072 bytes in 55ms
   02-02 15:51:12.256: D/dalvikvm(16606): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 301 objects / 23248 bytes in 55ms
   02-02 15:51:12.406: D/dalvikvm(16606): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 194 objects / 7816 bytes in 52ms
   02-02 15:51:12.556: D/dalvikvm(16606): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 104 objects / 3920 bytes in 52ms
   02-02 15:51:12.686: D/dalvikvm(16606): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 107 objects / 3968 bytes in 54ms
```

Could it be that the GC destorys an object which links the handler to the gridview? (The same behavior is produced when I use the Activity itself as OnItemClickhandler)

**Debug Result 1:**
I also tried it without starting another activity. My grid cells display some images which are lazy loaded from a webserver. When I scrolled it lost the event handler but when the asynctask set the new image I got it back and was able to click again.
But after scrolling I lost it again.

**Debug Result 2:**
After playing around I added a onscroll-handler which sets a new anonymous class as event handler which calls the onItemClicked-method of the activity. Just to see if this would work - it doesn't! 
I also added a log output in the anonymous method and in the on scroll. The on scroll gets called but the onItemClicked Event handler doesn't.
What could that mean?

**Debug Result 3:**
OnTouch gets fired even if onItemClicked doesn't.

Comment: The error doesn't appear to be related. Can you post part of your code? That would help.

Comment: Is this also happening if you comment the call to getMyIntent()? (And startActivity, of course)

Comment: @Luis Ollero - Yes it does, check the update I just written.

Comment: GC shouldn't be removing objects currently in use. I confessed I'm a bit lost. Are you lazy loading in the getView() of the Adapter?

Comment: your code looks pretty good. cant think what is wrong here. can you post rest of your activity code? and also the xml.

Comment: Yes, I start the async-tasks in the getView method and setting the images afterwards. But that works in many places in this app. I tried to reduce the objects in the grid and vola the bug is gone. If the GC doesn't get called everything's fine. The rest of the activity is much code but the important points are here. The strange thing is: the same list adapter is used in other spots without this behavior.

Comment: See Debug Result 2 for some strange new behavior. It seems that the view itself doesn't fire the events on clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with writing a a onitemclicked event fire mechanismen myself:

```
    grdVwUser.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int newy = (int)(event.getY());
            boolean val = false;
            int traveled = 0;

            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                traveled = Math.max(newy - lastTouchedY, lastTouchedY - newy);
            }
            // lastTouchedY is a member var
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                lastTouchedY = (int)event.getY();
            } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(traveled <= 40) {
                    int pos = grdVwUser.pointToPosition((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());      
                    Main.this.onItemClick(null, grdVwUser, pos, -1);
                    val = true;
                }
            }

            return val;
        }
    });
```